# ternary operator support for code model?

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

Is it possible to use the ternary operator in code generated by `com.sun.codemodel`?

I wish to generate the following statement:

```
this((A==null)?A.getSomething:null)
```

Comment: `(A==null)?A.getSomething:null` so if A is null you call a method on it? Ouch!

Comment: I suppose this is meant to use `A != null` in the condition (or the other operands swapped around).

Comment: @Paulo, I hope so because that is a code designed to fail

Comment: OUCH! A!=null was what I meant. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.sun.codemodel.JOp.cond` should already generate a ternary operator.  See the [source](http://java.net/projects/codemodel/sources/svn/content/trunk/codemodel/codemodel/src/main/java/com/sun/codemodel/JOp.java?rev=285):

```
public static JExpression cond(JExpression cond, JExpression ifTrue, JExpression ifFalse) {
     return new TernaryOp("?", ":", cond, ifTrue, ifFalse);
}
```